# arraylist in flash action script 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is it possible to use an arraylist in action script 3? I want to perform simple operations such as add() and remove()?

Thanks

Comment: ArrayList is in mx.collections. You can certainly use it in an AS3 project. It can be used when targeting the Flash Player or AIR.

Answer (score 10):

The default array primitive in AS3 is already an array list. You can use commands such as .push(object) and .pop() to add and remove to an array without defining its initial length.

Check out the Array reference here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Array.html

If you want to use something similar to remove, use:
myArray.splice(myArray.indexOf(object), 1);

Comment: LOL uhhh why did someone downvote this answer? I'll upvote... that's just plain stupid. You explained that there is already an array object in AS3 and explained some of the methods along with link.

Comment: Thanks for the simple yet great option.
my flash doesn't show additional options when i press ".", so i have to find thing by searching on internet.

Comment: full tutorial of array is here : http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3arrays/

Answer (score 0):

I gues somebody down voted the above answer because it's ambiguous. You can't push and pop to an ArrayList.

You need to addItem and getItemAt